Can I install Linux on the drive I booted the installer from, if the installer is loaded into RAM?
I'd like to install HoloISO (a Linux distro based on SteamOS) to a USB drive, as a full install. I've read from various sources, including this question, that to install Linux on to a USB drive, you need two USB drives - a source drive, to boot the installer from; and a target drive to install to - because a drive cannot install to itself. Quoting this answer to this question:

You can install from disk, but the installation can't repartition the disk or overwrite the partition containing the image from which you install.

However, I know that HoloISO allows you to load the installer entirely into your system's RAM - hence you can disconnect the source drive after fully loading the installer.
Therefore, my question is: can I boot from my source drive, then disconnect the drive after loading the installer entirely into RAM, then re-insert the source drive and install the distro to the drive (essentially repurposing it to become the target drive)? Is this possible?
P.S. I've said "Linux" not "HoloISO" in the question title, as I'd like to know about any Linux distribution that allows the installer to be loaded into RAM. Also, my question is not a duplicate of the question I linked above (Can I install a distro booted from a drive to the same drive?), as that question asks about USB linux installations in general - I'm asking specifically about installers that have been loaded entirely into RAM.


However, I know that HoloISO allows you to load the installer entirely into your system's RAM - hence you can disconnect the source drive after fully loading the installer.

If that's really what's happening, then, sure. Just because it can doesn't mean it does; technically, any Linux system could run completely from a RAM disk, given enough RAM (and time to copy data from the storage to said RAM).
It's just not an usual thing for installers of desktop Linux distros to do that these days (most installers are graphical, and bring some base packages that they don't have to download at installation time, so they can become rather large for machines with little RAM).
But there's nothing technically wrong with it! In fact, there's installers that really are just a bootloader, downloading the complete installer image via HTTP, which then does an installation. Some make use of the fact that many (not all) UEFI computer firmwares even support them in doing that
So yes, since you say this is not a duplicate of the previous question:
that is possible, and done on some systems.

Thank you for your answer! I've seen it as an option with some USB-based installations but HoloISO explicitly asks you, when booting from an installation USB drive, if you'd like to run the installer from the stick or load it into RAM. I managed to install the OS to a different drive, after disconnecting the source drive - and it worked - hence I asked this question (it's what I'd like to do). ...Also, I'd upvote your answer but I haven't enough reputation - I haven't used the Unix & Linux StackExchange before. Cheers =)
